# Enable mouse scrolling in message bodies in mutt

Tags: scroll, mutt, neomutt

I want to enable mouse scrolling while looking in message bodies in mutt. I can scroll when the emails are listed but not inside the body of one of the email when I open it.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this into your `.muttrc`

```
#scroll inside the message rather than the index
bind pager <up> previous-line
bind pager <down> next-line
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot!